# How to pass innerHTML of an element to an event handler attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game and would like the `innerHTML`  of the selected button to be passed to the `userChoice` variable.

See the codepen for the js.

http://codepen.io/BrianDGLS/pen/mnazG

```
<button id="Rock" onclick="gameMechanism();">Rock</button>
<button id="Paper" onclick="gameMechanism();">Paper</button>
<button id="Scissors" onclick="gameMechanism();">Scissors</button>
<button id="Lizard" onclick="gameMechanism();">Lizard</button>
<button id="Spock" onclick="gameMechanism();">Spock</button>
```

---

```
var userChoice = document.getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML;

function gameMechanism() {

    var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    switch (computerChoice) {
    case 0:
        computerChoice = "Rock";
        break;
    case 1:
        computerChoice = "Paper";
        break;
    case 2:
        computerChoice = "Scissors";
        break;
    case 3:
        computerChoice = "Lizard";
    case 4:
        computerChoice = "Spock";
        break;
    }

    document.write("You have chosen" + " " + userChoice + ", " + "The Computer has chosen" + " " + computerChoice + ". ");

    var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            document.write("The result is a tie!");
        } else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
            if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
                document.write("Rock crushes Scissors!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
                document.write("Paper covers Rock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
                document.write("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
                document.write("Rock crushes Lizard!");
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "Paper") {
            if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
                document.write("Scissors cuts Paper!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Rock") {
                document.write("Paper covers Rock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
                document.write("Paper disproves Spock");
            } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
                document.write("Lizard eats Paper!");
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "Scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "Rock") {
                document.write("Rock crushes Scissors!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
                document.write("Scissors cuts Paper!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
                document.write("Spock smashes Scissors!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
                document.write("Scissors decapitate Lizard!");
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "Lizard") {
            if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
                document.write("Scissors decapitates Lizard!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Rock") {
                document.write("Rock crushes Lizard!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
                document.write("Lizard poisons Spock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
                document.write("Lizard eats Paper!");
            }
        } else {
            if (choice2 === "Rock") {
                document.write("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
                document.write("Paper disproves Spock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
                document.write("Lizard poisons Spock!");
            } else if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
                document.write("Spock smashes Scissors!");
            }
        }
    };

    compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
```

Comment: Please include all code neccessary to reproduce the problem here. Remote sites can change, and then this question becomes useless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can do: `<button id="Rock" onclick="gameMechanism(innerHTML);">Rock</button>` [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m6jbvgn7/)

Comment: you can't use `document.write` after page loads, it will wipe out everything in the page. There is rarely a need to ever use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting all the buttons with the code and thus not getting the correct / selected value:

```
var userChoice = document.getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML;
```

What you could try is to alter the gameMechanism function

```
function gameMechanism(element) {
    var userChoice = element.innerHTML;
}
```

and then change the html to:

```
<button id="Rock" onclick="gameMechanism(this);">Rock</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send the choice to the gameMechanism() method and set userChoice inside that method if you need to.

`<button id="Rock" onclick="gameMechanism('ROCK');">Rock</button>`

Your gameMechanism() method declaration will need to be changed so that the parameter can be passed in.

`function gameMechanism(rpsChoice) {
    console.log('User chose ' + rpsChoice);`